# Data modell Laravel (Tourism Management )

Tags: php, laravel, database-design

I need some help with a school project. We are doing tourism management. We have 3 Actors (Customer, Advertiser, Tour Leader). 1. The customer buys the service. 2. The advertiser searches for customers.  3. Tour Leader conducts the tourism tour. How would I do that? The Advertiser creates the "Tour" on the Website (per Tour is 1 Leader planned). Should I use 4 tables? 1. User 2. Advertiser 3. Customer 4. Tour leader?

Comment: You better make 1 table `users` and add a `type` or `role` column in it that you can set to advertiser, customer and tour leader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i would do is separate them by roles, so you will have one table like "users" with id, everything you need and **"role_id"**, then table "roles" with 3 records (Customer, Advertiser, Tour leader, and how many do you have), and declare a "belongsTo" relation in User model something like this

```
public function role() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}
```

that way when needed in the middle of your application you can use $user->role to see what role he has, you can add more roles in the future if needed, and this should do

also if you think this should be a manyToMany relation, (for example one user can be Tour Leader and Advertiser in the same time) then you need third intermediate table, role_user...

good luck with your project